# Display wordpress popular posts to another website

Tags: php, wordpress, rss, ads, popularity

I have 2 websites "A" and "B"

Website "A" is based on wordpress
Website "B" is coded in php

How can I display popular posts of my wordpress website in website "B".

Is it possible to display it like how Native Advertisement shows. Like in the image below

[image: Content Recomendation]

Comment: Fetch latest posts of your WordPress website via RSS Feed and display them on website B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the json api plugin on the WordPress site and then on the PHP site write the code to query the json feed and output the posts. You can see more information about the json api plugin here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/other_notes/